# How to update item using expression syntax for dynamodb on a table with both hash and range

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I believe this should work, but it doesn't:

```
$response = $client->updateItem(array(
  'TableName' => 'ximoIsThisYou',
  'KeyConditionExpression' => 'rep_num = :v_hash and record_created = :v_range',
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
  ':v_hash'  => array('S' => $rep_num),
  ':v_range' => array('N' => $record_created),
  ':val1' => array('S' => '447747')
  ),
  'UpdateExpression' => 'set vimeo_id = :val1',
  'ReturnValues' => 'ALL_NEW'
));
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\ValidationException: 
AWS Error Code: ValidationException, Status Code: 400, 
AWS Request ID: UOPKLQER1MI3ANF48PU92IAC3VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, 
AWS Error Type: client, 
AWS Error Message: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'key' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null, 
User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.8.2 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
```

This however does work:

```
$response = $client->query(array(
  'TableName' => 'ximoIsThisYou',
  'KeyConditionExpression' => 'rep_num = :v_hash and record_created = :v_range',
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
  ':v_hash'  => array('S' => $rep_num),
  ':v_range' => array('N' => $record_created)
  ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`KeyConditionExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression) is a parameter used for [`Query`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html).

> The condition that specifies the key value(s) for items to be retrieved by the Query action.

You are trying to call [`UpdateItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html), which requires [`Key`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-Key). You are getting the validation error because you have not set the required request parameter `Key`.